# object instantiated by UINib not showing its proper class?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a xib file, which is a view, and I have designated it as a FooView class.

When I allocate it:

```
UINib *fooViewXib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FooView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
FooView *fooView = [[fooViewXib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] lastObject];
fooView.lolLabel.text = @"lol";
```

If I then ask it:

```
[fooView isKindOfClass:[FooView class]];
```

It says no...

Yet, if I NSLog the fooView object, it says it's a fooView. And if I NSLog the class of the fooView object directly, it shows as a FooView class.

Why does isKindOfClass not correctly identify this object, and how can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `lastObject`, loop through the array until you find a view with the correct class. Do it like this

```
NSArray *nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FooView" owner:self options:nil];
FooView *view;
for (id object in nibViews)
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[FooView class])
        view = object;
// do whatever you want with view
```

This will ensure that you get a view with the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to iterate through the array created by instantiating a nib when you can connect the object you want to an outlet. You don't say what class your code is part of, but lets assume it's a view controller. You can simply make `fooView` an outlet in your view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FooView* fooView;
@end
```

Set the type of File's Owner in the nib to `MyViewController` and connect the foo view to the `fooView` outlet of File's Owner. Now in your view controller you can just pass `self` as the nib's owner:

```
UINib *fooViewXib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"FooView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[fooViewXib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
```

After that, the `fooView` property will be connected to the right view.

Comment: I am trying to do a unit test...  All I want to do is inspect the subviews of a container view, and assert that the correct number of FooViews are there, but I can't because none of them seem to return true when asked if they are a kind of FooView class.  Yet, their description and their [self class] method returns "FooView", which is why I am confused and posting this question...

Comment: So I apparently can accomplish what I want by doing [NSStringFromClass([fooView class]) isEqualToString:@"FooView"] ... Which is exactly what isKindOfClass should be doing.. I don't get it.